# How can I feed data from Hibernate to the Weka Java API?

Tags: data-mining, java, weka

I am developing a data mining application with the Weka API, Java and MySQL DB connectivity. I want to feed data from the database to the algorithm. I used http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+Weka+in+your+Java+code#Instances-Database.

Since I use Hibernate and the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file has the database connection information, can't I just write a normal method in the DAO class to retrieve data and then pass that to the algorithm?

Comment: Yes. You can do exactly what you suggested. (If you need assistance in HOW to do this, please provide more information on what currently works and what not, where not and why not.)

Comment: Have you tried your suggestion and failed? I fail to see a minimal problem solving effort here?

Answer (score 1):

The Weka API is, unfortunately, in some points quite constrained. As such, you will need to have Instances objects. IIRC this its not an interface that you could implement otherwise, but an actual object you have to create.

Therefore, you will likely need to query all your database and produce `Instance`s out of it. Not using hibernate but raw database accesses will save you from doing things twice, thus needing twice as much memory.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently done this with Hibernate, but there is no way that a hibernate class can simply be put into WEKA. I've done it this way:

- generate a table in the database that has the model information available as you need it (I've done this since i would have needed to do very complex, time consuming queries for every row. This way, I do the heavy work once and just read it from a simple table)
- create you POJO, DAO and what not
- then just set-up your WEKA model

Sample Code (WEKA 3.7)

```
ArrayList<Attribute> atts = new ArrayList<Attribute>();
atts.add(new Attribute("attribute1"));
atts.add(new Attribute("attribute1"));
atts.add(new Attribute("id", (ArrayList<String>) null));
data = new Instances("yourData", atts, 0);

DAOModel dao = getYourDaoModelHereFromHibernateHoweverYouWantIt();
for (Model m : dao.findAll()) {
   vals = new double[data.numAttributes()];
   vals[0] = m.getAttribute1();
   vals[1] = m.getAttribute2();
   vals[2] = data.attribute(2).addStringValue(m.getId());
   data.add(new DenseInstance(1.0, vals));
}
```

`data` now has the proper format and the algorithms can work with it (you could also save it to an .arff file if you want to work with the GUI)